# Question about class members in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, member

I have seen the following style of defining class members; however, I have only seen it done for objects.  I'm having difficulty figuring out if it will work for structures (i.e. NSUInteger or enum) and primitives (i.e. int, uint, float) as well.

Here is my aClass.h

```
typedef enum {
    kValue0 = 0,
    kValue1
} CustomType;

@interface aClass : CCLayerColor {

    NSUInteger _aMember;
    CustomType _anotherMember;
    float _aThirdMember;
    NSString _aFourthMember;

}

@property (assign) NSUInteger aMember;
@property (assign) NSUInteger anotherMember;
@property (assign) NSUInteger aThirdMember;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString aFourthMember;

@end
```

And here is my aClass.m

```
@implementation aClass

@synthesize aMember = _aMember;
@synthesize anotherMember = _anotherMember;
@synthesize aThirdMember = _aThirdMember;
@synthesize aFourthMember = _aFourthMember;

- (id)init {

    if( (self=[super init] )) {

        NSUInteger _aMember = 100;
        CustomType _anotherMember = kValue0;
        float _aThirdMember = 200.0f;
        NSString _aFourthMember = [[NSString alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}
```

In testing, I find that if I call the synthesized helper functions (get/set), I am able to access the member via _aMember or aMember equally well.  I don't understand why, though?  It seems that '@synthesize aMember = _aMember;' would only work as intended with objects, where  both aMember and _aMember would point to the same memory location.  I suppose I just don't understand what's happening here.

Can anyone tell me why this works?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `@synthesize aMember = _aMember;` code is doing is creating a separate name for the instance variable and the property accessor. Take the following code for example:

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSUInteger _aMember;
}

@property (assign) NSUInteger aMember;

@end


@implementation MyClass
@synthesize aMember = _aMember;

// Above @synthesize statement will create an accessor & mutator similar to this:

- (NSUInteger)aMember {
    return _aMember;
}

- (void)setAMember:(NSUInteger)aMember {
    _aMember = aMember;
}

@end
```

So we have created a private instance variable `_aMember`, and public property `aMember`. In the `MyClass`, you can still access the properties and set the value of the instance variables by calling `self.aMember`. In practice, this behaves exactly the same as setting the ivar directly (note this is all the mutator above does anyway). Also note that the difference between these two assignments becomes significant when using `retain` semantics (i.e. when your property is declared as `@property (retain) UIView *myView;`). When this is used, the mutator generated by `@synthesize` also handles the retain/release of assignments properly, and so calling `self.myView = newView` will behave differently to `myView = newView`.

So this notation does the same as for `id` types, in that it is a simple renaming of the ivar, for convention's sake.

Also, as @jer pointed out, you have an issue in your code sample with shadowing of your declared instance variables - in your `init` method you are creating new variables with the same names as your instance variables. Instead, try `_aMember = 100;`. Also, `NSString` is an `id` type, and so the declarations in your header file should be `NSString *_aFourthMember;` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aFourthMember;`.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** More detail about accessors/mutators using retain semantics.

When I was learning about this stuff, I found it incredibly useful to know what was going on inside an automatically generated mutator. For a property declared `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView;`, it's something like this:

```
- (void)setMyView:(UIView*)newView {
    if (newView != myView) {
        [newView retain];
        [myView release];
        myView = newView;
    }
}
```

This is used to assign new objects to the `myView` property, through the use of `self.myView` (if you're calling from within the owning class), or `theClass.myView` (if you're calling from another class). If the new assignment is different from the existing one, it is retained, the old value is released, and the pointer is assigned to myView.

Comment: Thanks, @StuDev.  This is very helpful.  So, in your example, if I use `myView = newView`, then will the previous object referenced by myView not get released?  This would constitute as a memory leak, if I didn't manually `[myView release]` it before setting myView to reference a different object and myView was the only reference retaining it, right?

Comment: @Jonathan, that's right. `myView = newView;` would leak its previous value, and what's more `newView` wouldn't even be retained, and so you would likely end up getting a bad access error trying to call `myView` later in your code (enter NSZombies...). I'll update my answer with a bit more detail about this.

Comment: It is incorrect to assume the retainCount will be 1 or 0 in the above example.

Comment: @bbum: Well, yes. I was going by @Jonathan's assumption that myView was the only object involved in the retaining/releasing. I'll update to make this clear.

Comment: But it isn't the only object;  it is a subclass of UIView.  UIView's internal implementation details may or may not cause the absolute retain count to be 1 and that may change at any time...

Comment: Also; `myView` is *not* nil in that example which is exactly why the over-release causes a crash.  If it were `nil`, no crash would happen.

Comment: Fair point - I missed some subtleties there, and described the over-release situation badly. You know what, I'll just remove that bit :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two fundamental problems.

- Shadowing; and
- Assuming ObjC objects are scalar types.

Effectively, you're declaring the type of your string member to be `NSString` instead of a pointer to an NSString `NSString*`. All Objective-C objects are pointers to things. Even `id` itself is declared as a pointer to an objc object.

Secondly, you're shadowing your ivars in your init method by declaring local variables with the same names as your ivars. Just set your ivars, no need to declare them as local variables. For instance:

```
_aThirdMember = 200.0f;
```

Will set the ivar, whereas:

```
float _aThirdMember = 200.0f;
```

creates a `float` on the stack (a local variable) which will go away when init finishes being called. Not what you want.

You also really need to read the [properties programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html), it is very clear on the last part of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @jer.  You are right that I needed to read that document.